# Android in-app Billing (without Sample application)

Tags: android

Thanks for the previous answer.
Recently I m working over a Commercial based Project in Android, Where I need to implement Billing & transaction Functionality with the Products. So There is method of Implementing this, By configuring the Sample Application with my App, But Restriction for me is not to use This Sample Application, Just have to do the Coding for it.So if anybody knows any alternate way to do it, Or any Code Module is available for this Please reply me.It will be a great help in my terms.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sure I've done it :-) Here's another simplified tutorial as an alternative to the google code:

http://www.anddev.org/advanced-tutorials-f21/simple-inapp-billing-payment-t52060.html

Comment: The link u given is nice and simple, i implemented it and its working fine, but as soon as i purchsed the item and come back to main page it crashes, i send u the log in this link http://pastebin.com/YpGywhUw

Comment: "Base64DecoderException: single trailing character at offset 19" Looks like you've pasted in an illegal character into your secret key.

Comment: you mean in this place String base64EncodedPublicKey = "YOUR PUBLIC KEY HERE";

Comment: Yeah it looks like it from the stacktrace